# storcli64 not importing a foreign dg with disks previously offline

Tags: raid, megaraid, storcli

I experienced a weird cascade of disk "failures" w/in a few minutes on a AVAGO MegaRAID SAS 9361-8i on Linux.  During this time, a hot spare drive was never spun up.  Ignoring a few unrelated JBOD drives (which seem fine), the defined DG was RAID6.  When the third disk failed, the DG was taken offline.  Because the disks failed together so quickly, I suspect that they're not the real problem.  I thought that perhaps I could try to recover the DG.

I rebooted the device, and now the disks are marked as "foreign":

```
Drive Information :
=================

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                   Sp Type 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
23:0     24 GHS   -  3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD4000FYYZ-01UL1B1  D  -    
23:1     31 UGood F  3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD4000F9YZ-09N20L1  U  -    
23:2     25 UGood F  3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD4000F9YZ-09N20L1  U  -    
23:3     30 UGood F  3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD4000F9YZ-09N20L1  U  -    
23:4     26 UGood F  3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD4000F9YZ-09N20L1  U  -    
23:5     29 UGood F  3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD4000F9YZ-09N20L0  U  -    
23:6     27 UGood F  3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD4000F9YZ-09N20L1  U  -    
23:7     33 UGood F  3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD4000F9YZ-09N20L1  U  -    
23:8     28 UGood F  3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD4000F9YZ-09N20L1  U  -    
23:9     32 UGood F  3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD4000F9YZ-09N20L1  U  -    
23:10    42 JBOD  -  3.638 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD40EFRX-68N32N0    U  -    
23:11    41 JBOD  -  3.638 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD40EFZX-68AWUN0    U  -    
23:18    39 JBOD  -  1.819 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B Hitachi HDS722020ALA330 U  -    
23:23    40 JBOD  -  3.638 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD40EFZX-68AWUN0    U  -    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note that I don't know why they're marked as "foreign"; I've not moved, added, or removed any disks.

A preview:

```
# /opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64 /c0/fall import preview
CLI Version = 007.1705.0000.0000 Mar 31, 2021
Operating system = Linux 3.10.0-1160.25.1.el7.x86_64
Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = Operation on foreign configuration Succeeded


FOREIGN PREVIEW :
===============

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
DG Arr Row EID:Slot DID Type  State BT      Size PDC  PI SED DS3  FSpace TR 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 -   -   -        -   RAID6 OfLn  N  25.466 TB dflt N  N   dflt Y      N  
 0 0   -   -        -   RAID6 Dgrd  N  25.466 TB dflt N  N   dflt Y      N  
 0 0   0   23:9     32  DRIVE Offln N   3.637 TB dflt N  N   dflt -      N  
 0 0   1   23:1     31  DRIVE Onln  N   3.637 TB dflt N  N   dflt -      N  
 0 0   2   23:2     25  DRIVE Onln  N   3.637 TB dflt N  N   dflt -      N  
 0 0   3   23:3     30  DRIVE Onln  N   3.637 TB dflt N  N   dflt -      N  
 0 0   4   23:4     26  DRIVE Onln  N   3.637 TB dflt N  N   dflt -      N  
 0 0   5   23:5     29  DRIVE Onln  N   3.637 TB dflt N  N   dflt -      N  
 0 0   6   23:6     27  DRIVE Offln N   3.637 TB dflt N  N   dflt -      N  
 0 0   7   23:7     33  DRIVE Onln  N   3.637 TB dflt N  N   dflt -      N  
 0 0   8   23:8     28  DRIVE Offln N   3.637 TB dflt N  N   dflt -      N  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

DG=Disk Group Index|Arr=Array Index|Row=Row Index|EID=Enclosure Device ID
DID=Device ID|Type=Drive Type|Onln=Online|Rbld=Rebuild|Optl=Optimal|Dgrd=Degraded
Pdgd=Partially degraded|Offln=Offline|BT=Background Task Active
PDC=PD Cache|PI=Protection Info|SED=Self Encrypting Drive|Frgn=Foreign
DS3=Dimmer Switch 3|dflt=Default|Msng=Missing|FSpace=Free Space Present
TR=Transport Ready

Total foreign Drive Groups = 1
```

When I try to import, it fails with an error:

```
# /opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64 /c0/fall import 
CLI Version = 007.1705.0000.0000 Mar 31, 2021
Operating system = Linux 3.10.0-1160.25.1.el7.x86_64
Controller = 0
Status = Failure
Description = Incomplete foreign configuration
```

I thought perhaps to try to force the previewed-offline drives online, but:

```
# /opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64 /c0/e23/s8 set online
CLI Version = 007.1705.0000.0000 Mar 31, 2021
Operating system = Linux 3.10.0-1160.25.1.el7.x86_64
Controller = 0
Status = Failure
Description = Set Drive Online Failed.

Detailed Status :
===============

------------------------------------------------
Drive      Status  ErrCd ErrMsg                 
------------------------------------------------
/c0/e23/s8 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
------------------------------------------------
```

This occurs with all three.

Is there some way to recover this?  Also, has anyone heard of this sort of sudden cascade of disk failures w/o a hot space spinning up?